# my Date Util formatter does not return my intended date format need help,

Tags: java

**Date Util**

public class DateUtil {

public static Date StringToDate(String date) {

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date convertedDate = null;
try {
  convertedDate = sdf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return convertedDate;
```

}

}

**The String Input when i call it**

2018/06/08

**The value it returns is**

Fri Jun 08 00:00:00 CST 2018

Comment: *"A Java Date is a container for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"* - `Date` does not have any concept of "format", when you print the `Date`, the object is using a "human readable" format (based on you current configuration) to display the value for you. If you want to "display" the `Date` in a different format, you use a date formatter.  Since it's 2018 now, you should be using the newer date/time API introduced in Java 8 (or the three ten back port if you're not using Java 8)

Comment: so that's why its returning that value,thanks for the info,,,i'll do that,